# ros publishing without loop?

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I am publishing a "geometry_msgs::Twist" with out a while(n.ok()) loop it is not affecting the topic. But I can not use a infinite loop. Everytime according the scan data I have to modify the linear and angular velocity of the Twist msgs. Is there any way out to affect the topic without using the loop.. Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195212/ros-publishing-without-loop?/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-17**:
can you write more about issue , also if possible the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some possiblities to publish outside the while loop, e. g.

--> publishing in a subcriber callback (suitable if your node dows only few processing and your published out message only depends on the incoming messages, e. g. for any kind of republishers)
--> publishing in a timer callback (if you want to publish at constant rate outside the while (ros::ok()) loop  )

Note that you should set up your publisher before initializing the Subscriber/Timer and your publisher should be visible inside the callback (local publisher object not possible anymore).

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0